# Discussion Board Definition

Tags: discussion-board

What is the definition of a Discussion Board? I'm just looking for a basic definition including some of the features that may be also found on d Discussion Board.

Answer (score 0):

Discussion boards provide forums for site participants to discuss important and useful topics with each other. Most site templates include the ability to create discussion boards, and many sites and workspace sites have a built-in discussion board called Team Discussion.

By default, a discussion board shows the most recent discussion first, as well as the number of replies for each discussion. That way, you can quickly see which discussions have the most recent activity and which ones are the most popular. However, a moderator can modify and add views to customize the discussion board. Participants can also customize their own views of the discussion board. If a site is set up to receive e-mail, participants can add items to the discussion board from their e-mail application.
More details here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/create-customize-and-moderate-a-discussion-board-HA101808839.aspx

Within SharePoint 2013 the discussion bard got an thorough remake. In SharePoint the discussion board was just an list within a page or site. Within the  discussion board a topic and some information about the number of replies was displayed.
http://joostvanlier.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/sharepoint-2013-discussion-boards/